# Ubuntu 12.04 WiFi wpa 2 connected to router but Can only be accessed by ssh

Tags: 12.04, networking, file-sharing, wpa-supplicant

The problem is that my Ubuntu server 12.04 can only be accessed by ssh. It connects to the router with a wifi wpa 2 encryption. Im not using a firewall, and it should be sharing to both windows and mac using samba and afp. This works when the connection is wired, but not through the wireless? Can anyone directe me or give me any ideas as what to try. Thank you in advance.

---

Here is a little more detail

iwconfig (I think the problem is here - I do not have an IP address?)

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"Tomato"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.452 GHz  Access Point: 20:4E:7F:10:18:54   
          Bit Rate=121.5 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=56/70  Signal level=-54 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:1  Invalid misc:94   Missed beacon:0

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

dmesg | grep eth0

```
[    3.207518] r8169 0000:04:00.0: eth0: RTL8168e/8111e at 0xf8414000, 14:da:e9:6b:b1:74, XID 0c200000 IRQ 46
[    3.207525] r8169 0000:04:00.0: eth0: jumbo features [frames: 9200 bytes, tx checksumming: ko]
[    8.312266] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   12.870001] r8169 0000:04:00.0: eth0: link down
[   12.870368] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
```

dmesg | grep wlan0

```
[   45.689429] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   45.693155] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   48.743038] wlan0: authenticate with 20:4e:7f:10:18:54 (try 1)
[   48.745261] wlan0: authenticated
[   48.776724] wlan0: associate with 20:4e:7f:10:18:54 (try 1)
[   48.780280] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 20:4e:7f:10:18:54 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[   48.780290] wlan0: associated
[   48.787054] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing problem in your system configuration. reconfigure your router . Please check dhcp and make sure that your internet connection is shared.